# r if else based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataset data1 as follows

```
          Group     Code
          Blue      1333
          Blue      4444
          Blue      9876
          Blue      8785
          Red       3145
          Red       8756
          Red       9745
          Red       8754
```

Second dataset data2 is as follows

```
          Id       Description
          1333     Sea Weed
          4444     Honey Roasted Peanut
          8754     Green Tea
          8756     Potato Chips
          3145     Strawberry Grahams
          8787     Arizona Ice Tea
```

I am trying to create a third column in my 2nd Dataset , data2 which stores

```
           1  - If the code is from blue Group in Data1 and matches with Id in Data2, Data1$Group = Blue && Data1$Code == Data2$Id

           2  - If the code is from Red Group in Data1 and matches with Id in Data2, Data1$Group = Red && Data1$Code == Data2$Id

           0  - If the Id in Data2 does not match the Code in Data1 , regardless of whether it is Blue or Red group.
```

The final dataset should look like this

```
          Id       Description             Result
          1333     Sea Weed                1  
          4444     Honey Roasted Peanut    1
          8754     Green Tea               2
          8756     Potato Chips            2 
          3145     Strawberry Grahams      2 
          8787     Arizona Ice Tea         0
```

Need some assistance

Comment: `dat2$Result <- dat1$Group[match(dat2$Id, dat1$Code)]` will give you the colours - which you can then recode

Comment: Since you included the tag 'dplyr' in your post, here's a 'dplyr' answer: `dat2 <- dat2 %>% left_join(dat1,by=c('Id'='Code')) %>% select(Id,Description,Result=Group)`  (though the base R answer is easier follow...)

Answer (score 1):

Easier base R answer is to use `merge`

```
> merge(data1, data2, by.x='Code', by.y='Id', all.y=T)

  Code Group          Description
1 1333  Blue             Sea Weed
2 3145   Red   Strawberry Grahams
3 4444  Blue Honey Roasted Peanut
4 8754   Red            Green Tea
5 8756   Red         Potato Chips
6 8787  <NA>      Arizona Ice Tea
```

If your heart is set on using `dplyr`, then renaming the column is the easiest way to do this is to rename the column so that it matches the merged table

```
data2 %>% rename(Code=Id) %>% left_join(data1)
```